# Get Current user login to Linux via Daemon

Tags: linux, glibc, init

I am logging a user that is login to a linux system at an interval of 1-minute. The logging will be done using an init.d script owned by root and it auto start at bootup.

I tried using getlogin() and getlogin_r() with a simple init.d script. However, it will work if I run the init.d script via console but when I register the init.d script via chkconfig --add [initscript] and reboot the system, it runs as check via ps -ef but when I checked the log file, the username is empty.

Did I miss something? Is their an alternative approach of getting the login user?

Comment: Make sure you explicitly flush or close the log file, you might be suffering from buffering.

Comment: I am not sure i follow exactly what you want to do, but possibly the `last` command does what you want. It will provide a list of logins (and some other stuff). There is also `lastb` which lists failed logins.

Comment: *"The logging will be done using an init.d script owned by root and it auto start at bootup...."* - Nowadays you usually use Systemd, not init scripts. Systemd does not manage the init scripts well. For example, `rng-tools` does not start properly as an init script because Systemd is driving the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getlogin()  returns  a  pointer to a string containing the name of the user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process, or a null pointer if this  information  cannot  be  determined.

A script run through init does not have a controlling terminal. Whereas, if you run a script via console, the console is the controlling (virtual) terminal.

`getlogin()` does not do what you want to do. I assume you should have a look for `users` and `who` commands.

Comment: I'll check the "users" and "who".

Comment: Tested "who" and "w" command and it works with the use of popen() and pclose(). The final implementation will be done in C/C++ while the init.d script will control the start|stop|restart of the application.

Answer (score 0):

@ypnos,
I did not bother to check the **who.c** you provided from the link [github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/who.c](http://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/who.c).

I did a different approach from the code snippet below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmpx.h>
#include <time.h>


int main (void)
{
    struct utmpx *UtmpxPtr = NULL;
    struct tm *TimePtr = NULL;
    time_t TimeInSec;
    char TimeBuff[32];

    printf("...Start \"who logged-in\"...\n");

    setutxent();
    while ((UtmpxPtr = getutxent()) != NULL)
    {
        if (UtmpxPtr->ut_type != USER_PROCESS)
        {
            continue;
        }

        TimeInSec = UtmpxPtr->ut_tv.tv_sec;
        TimePtr = localtime(&TimeInSec);
        strftime(TimeBuff, sizeof(TimeBuff), "%Y-%m-%d|%H:%M", TimePtr);

        printf("%s|%s|%s\n", UtmpxPtr->ut_user, TimeBuff, UtmpxPtr->ut_host);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    endutxent();
    return 0;
}
```